# How to play random sound form assets folder on button click?

Tags: android, media-player

I need to play random sound out of 300 sounds placed in assets folder. 
While implementing the problem I am getting is that its always playing the first sound from assets on button click.

```
MediaPlayer player;
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.machine); 

player = new MediaPlayer();

playSound  = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_play);

AssetManager aMan = this.getAssets();
try 
{
    filelist = aMan.list("");
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

playSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{           
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(filelist.length);

        try 
        {
            String mediaFile = filelist[randomInt];
            descriptor = getAssets().openFd(mediaFile);
                player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),descriptor.getStartOffset(),descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();
            player.prepare();
                        player.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
filelist = aMan.list("");
```

to this:

```
filelist = aMan.list("/assets");
```